# When using CSS how specific does selector have to be?

Tags: css

I am wondering how specific selectors have to be for isolating properties in CSS. For example if,

```
.samples table td{}
```

and

```
.samples td{}
```

target the same thing, which one should I use?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on context. You should be as specific as is necessary in order to clearly communicate your intent. As a `td` will always be inside a `table`, placing it in front is somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can be as specific as you want to be. Both your examples will work exactly the same.

I work on the principle of being as specific as is currently necessary. I do this because I may need to be more specific in the future, and need to override what I've previously done.

For example,

```css
p a {
  color: red;
}
.test p a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p><a class="btn" href="#">LINK</a></p>
</div>
```

In the above example, the first style makes the link red, but lets say for whatever reason I want that link to be a different color on a different page which has a unique parent class, I can use that to be more specific, which I've done in the second style.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about CSS specificity - here is [more info](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) on css tricks.
It entirely depends on the element you are targetting.

Answer (score 0):

> for isolation purpose your hierarchy should be as long as
>   possible(make sure its correct) you should use ".samples table td{}"
>   for isolation purpose
>   it will be better(suggested but optional) to use '>'  in css like this:
>       .samples > table > td{}

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, technically speaking, there is no rule that says how specific you should be. Ultimately it comes down to personal choice.

**However**, it is generally considered best practice to aim to be as least specific as possible, when possible. This ultimately results in far more maintainable and composable CSS (favour composition over inheritance is a rule that applies to CSS, not just object-orientated programming languages).

That said, this can often depend on the use case. For instance, if you're developing a widget you may want to use a more specific selector, such as the following example:

```
<div class="my-login-widget">
    <input type="text" class="username">
</div>

.my-login-widget .username {
    // your styles
}
```

Due to one of the limitations in CSS, if you had a global `.username` class then your login widget's field would still inherit the styling of that class declaration - these limitations have lead to naming conventions such as the [BEM naming convention](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/) that promote a more structured naming convention - resulting in a class name of `.my-login-widget__username` being used.

Ultimately conventions such as the BEM naming convention leads to a reduction of class name styling clashes and CSS that is easier to easy with because you're able to infer the structure of the HTML based on the class names.